# What is a good way to get the effects of :before and :after for input submit buttons?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, submit-button

It seems browsers dislike the use of :before and :after for submit buttons in particular, which I'm guessing has something to do with click jacking prevention. However, it basically ruins a specific style I'm trying to achieve, and my alternatives to replicate the effect are poor.

How can I produce an effect similar to :before and :after for submit buttons without using scripts?  I am able to generate additional elements (via. server scripts) for each occurrence of a submit button, if need be. Ideally not wrapper elements, but I could make those work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `<button type="submit">` element so that you can add additional `<span>` elements within the button if you simply need more DOM nodes.

[`:before` will also work on `button` elements](http://jsfiddle.net/pz2t2/).

Comment: This sounds perfect, as long as <button type="submit"> functions the same as <input type="submit">. There aren't any behavior differences I should be aware of, right?

Comment: @Hamster, not as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Hamster, in chrome it wouldn't render the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements with `type="button"` but it did for `type="checkbox"`. I've removed the statement, as it's provably false.

Comment: Hang on, I was mistaken. I had <input type=button> and <button>s mixed together. Now I understand how this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<span>` or `<div>` elements.

Here are some examples of use with `<span>` on :

- `<input type="text"/>`
- `<input type="submit"/>`
- `<button type="button">`
- `<button type="submit">`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/W8Bzs/)**